# Allow reference to variables in class declared with Any

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have a function what take a List It can be many difference classes that contain a number of fields (open, high, low, close). The classes contain other fields. But I don't want to write one function for each class that I am going to map over. Is there a way to allow for the fields to be specified without getting "unresolved reference"

```
fun createTA4JBarsFromAlgobars(timebars: List<Any?>, name: String): BaseBarSeries? {

    val series = BaseBarSeriesBuilder().withName(name).build()

//all it.unixSecond etc. Get unresolved reference with compiling

    timebars.map { series.addBar(utilService.unixtimeToZoneDateTime(it.unixSecond), it.open, it.high, it.low, it.close, it.volume) }

    return series

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is extremely rare to ever have a reason to have a `List<Any>`. (In 12 years of Java and Kotlin use, I don't recall ever doing that.) If there is some property you want to get from all the items in the list, you should have all of them inherit from a common interface that defines those properties. Then you can create a list of that interface type and put in instances of various different classes that all conform to that interface. For example:

```
interface TimeBar {
    val unixSecond: Long
    val open: Float
    val close: Float
    val high: Float
    val low: Float
    val volume: Float
}

// Make all your various classes for your list implementers of the above interface.
// Then make your list a `List<TimeBar>`.
```

In your case, if each class type doesn't have `high`, `low`, etc. properties, but instead they all get added to your chart in various different ways, you could instead create a common interface for adding the instance to your chart, for example:

```
interface TimeBar {
    fun addToBaseBarSeries(series: BaseBarSeries)
}

// in each of your classes, some implementation of the above function:
override fun addToBaseBarSeries(series: BaseBarSeries) {
    series.addBar(utilService.unixtimeToZoneDateTime(unixSecond), open, high, low, close, volume)
}
```

You are also using `map` improperly. It is not for creating side effects. It is for creating a new list of a different type. You should be using a for loop instead.

Comment: The classes are all database entities. So I think the second solution is probably better. If I remeber correctly all the fields need to be in the entity to be written to the DB.

Comment: The downside with the second solution is that you have to write out unique functions for each class, but that might be necessary if they all appear on the chart differently.